# Validate Authenticode signature on EXE - C++ without CAPICOM

Tags: c++, winapi, cryptography, authenticode

I'm writing a function for an installer DLL to verify the Authenticode signature of EXE files already installed on the system.

The function needs to:

> A) verify that the signature is valid.
>   B) verify that the signer is our organization.

Because this is in an installer, and because this needs to run on older Win2k installations, I **don't** want to rely on CAPICOM.dll, as it may not be on the target system.

The [WinVerifyTrust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388208(VS.85).aspx) API works great to solve (A).

I need to find a way to compare a known certificate (or properties therein) to the one that signed the EXE in question.

Comment: +1... if anyone can come up with a library that'll do it even on a non-Windows platform I'll be happy. I'd like to be able to check an .EXE is Microsoft-signed from inside Linux.

Comment: @bobince, Mono has both the **signcode** and **chktrust** tools that works (if you install the required root certificates) on every platform that Mono supports (S390x if you like ;-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use [CryptQueryObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380264(VS.85).aspx).

This KB-article demonstrates the use: [How To Get Information from Authenticode Signed Executables](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/323809).

To the commenter that asked about how to do it without the Windows-APIs, I am not aware of any library that can do it, but the format is documented here: [Windows Authenticode Portable Executable Signature Format](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/winlogo/drvsign/Authenticode_PE.mspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the signature is valid, its certificate chain will contain your certificate. [CertGetCertificateChain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376078%28VS.85%29.aspx) will get that chain.

Comment: Do you mean that the WINTRUST_DATA structure contains the certificate? Or perhaps CertGetCertificateChain can be used on a file directly - I just can't figure out how. I must be missing something obvious. Thanks in advance for more details.