# C#: How to detect tampering of authenticode signed file

Tags: c#, .net, authenticode, signtool

I'm trying to write a C# program that verifies the digital signature of exe's. The exe's are signed with an authenticode certificate, and I want to detect tampering.

I've been able to create a SignedCms instance as described here: [Get timestamp from Authenticode Signed files in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281057/get-timestamp-from-authenticode-signed-files-in-net)

I assumed SignedCms.CheckSignature would do the trick, but this method never throws an exception... Even not when I modify some bits of the exe...

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you've scoured the .NET Framework docs and didn't find what you needed.  The answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301024/validate-authenticode-signature-on-exe-c-without-capicom) has a link that describes how to use the native Windows CryptQueryObject function to verify a signature.  So all that's left is to check out [PInvoke.NET to see how to bring that function into .NET](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/crypt32/CryptQueryObject.html).

Comment: David Pope: So all a hacker needs to do is overwrite the CryptQueryObject ? lol - security by obscurity doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just shell to `signtool.exe /verify`, and check the result?

I recently wrote a simple app which signs executables using the same method, and it works great.

[Signtool on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Signing an executable is pointless, I can just remove your signing code, or change the signing key. with ilasm + ildasm ... In order for that to work, you'd need a trusted root certificate installed on the OS, and have the os verify the key -  a key which was itselfs signed by a trusted authority, exactly like SSL.

Comment: We sign with a public trusted cert and verify the trust chain.