# Check whether a given executable is digitally signed and valid?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, code-signing, authenticode

In my `C#`/`.NET` application I have to **check if a given executable is digitally signed** *(preferably without `Exception` testing.)*

Then I need to **check if its certificate is valid** *(based on installed root certificates)* and **if the files content is valid for the signature**.

There are so many classes in the `BCL`, I don't know where to start & what to use, and anything I've found so far doesn't eliminate my confusion...

I'd like to do something like this, *without* `P/Invoke` if possible:

```
bool IsSignedFile(string path);  
Cert GetCertificateFromSignedFile(string path);
bool IsValidCertificate(Cert cert)
Sig GetSignatureFromSignedFile(string path);
bool IsValidSignature(string path, Sig sig, Cert cert);
```

**Added clarification:**

The big problem I currently have is that I don't find a way to obtain the signature of such a file in an easy way. Still hope there is a provided, managed, `BCL` solution as I would be surprised if exactly that part is missing. *(For the certificate this can be done with just [`X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.createfromsignedfile.aspx), validating that is possible, too)*
*I'd prefer not mixing that 50% work done with `P/Invoke` code or a big different library.*

I've found a [`AuthenticodeSignatureInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.authenticodesignatureinformation.aspx) class, no information about using that for a given executable though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622732/c-how-to-detect-tampering-of-authenticode-signed-file

Comment: I hope this won't be a duplicate of a not answered question ;)

Comment: The question linked to has three answers from what I can see. (None of them were accepted, but that's not to say they aren't relevant). There is another similar one at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301024/validate-authenticode-signature-on-exe-c-without-capicom but everything points to the use of p/invoke being required unfortunately.

Comment: These answers are _"parse the output of some other tool"_ and _"use platform invoke"_. There is a huge [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.aspx) for that topic, worst case to not use something of it.

Comment: @ordag: Most solutions I've found use P/Invoke. May I ask why you don't want to?

Comment: @robjb It seems false to use it when there is so much about this topic available, just missing the guide how to use it. Also I may not be allowed to use P/Invoke in the developed application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using only managed code. The mono project has it's own **[signcode](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/security/signcode.cs)** and **[chktrust](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/security/chktrust.cs)** tools that allows you to sign and verify Authenticode(tm) signatures.

Both use the [Mono.Security.dll](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security) assembly, which works fine under Windows, and all the code is licensed under the MIT.X11 license (so you can pretty much do what you want with it).

However you'll need a bit of extra logic to check the root certificate, since Mono uses it's own stores - not the one on Windows. That should not be a big issue since .NET (since v2) provides classes that query/access the user/machine certificate stores.

**Disclaimer:** *I wrote most of the code above ;-)*

Comment: @poupou Can't figure out how to get anything but reason 6 using Mono.Security.dll. Even looking at the code, it should only get reason 6 if you call IsTrusted() or if there wasn't already a reason from verifying the signature after setting the FileName. Problem is, I know a file I'm testing has an invalid signature, yet it somehow passes all the first set of checks in CheckSignature() and ends up with a trusted root error anyway. Is this a bug in the signature checks?

Answer (score 4):

[Determining if a file has a valid digital signature](http://geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2007/05/04/112250.aspx) using PInvoke in case you don't find the managed solution